# CLion C++ fatal error: 'process.h' file not found

Tags: c++

When I use CLion on a Mac to compile C++ code for highlight removal in a single image, there is an error:
[image: screenshot]

Please help me fix it.

```
#ifndef QX_CVPR09_CTBF_BASIC_H
#define QX_CVPR09_CTBF_BASIC_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <process.h>
#include <direct.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <memory.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>      // For greater<int>()
#include <iostream>
#if _MSC_VER > 1020   // if VC++ version is > 4.2
   using namespace std;  // std c++ libs implemented in std
#endif
#define QX_DEF_PADDING                  10
#define QX_DEF_THRESHOLD_ZERO           1e-6
class   qx_timer        {public: void start();  float stop(); void time_display(char *disp=""); void fps_display(char *disp=""); private: clock_t m_begin; clock_t m_end;};
```

It's a part of my code. The full code is too long.

Comment: post a code - not an image

Comment: Is that the same process.h as this one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process.h

Comment: Please post your code and the error message as text.

Comment: sorry i have update the code

Answer (score 3):

[process.h](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process.h)

> process.h is a C header file which contains function declarations and
>   macros used in working with threads and processes. Most C compilers
>   that target DOS, Windows 3.1x, Win32, OS/2, Novell NetWare or DOS
>   extenders supply this header and the library functions in their C
>   library. Neither the header file nor most of the functions are defined
>   by either the ANSI/ISO C standard or by POSIX.

Depends on which platform you compile and what standard you use. If you are on linux or compile with c99/ansi standard then this header will probably just not be available (which might be your error)

Comment: thanks i use mac to compile it and i think it's c++ code

Comment: @RussellLu Do you mean [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS)? (You may also be running Windows on a Mac.)